# Trying to include GSON in Play! 2.0 project

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, gson, sbt

I've added `"com.google.gson" % "gson" % "2.2"` to my AppDependencies but when I run play update, I get:

> [info] Updating
>   {file:/Users/levinotik/Dev/scala/throw-away/myFirstApp/}myFirstApp...
>   [warn]  module not found: com.google.gson#gson;2.1.0
>   [warn] ==== local: tried [warn]
>   /Users/levinotik/dev/scala/play-2.0.4/framework/../repository/local/com.google.gson/gson/2.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried [warn]
>   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/google/gson/gson/2.1.0/gson-2.1.0.pom
>   [warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots Repository: tried [warn]
>   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/com/google/gson/gson/2.1.0/gson-2.1.0.pom
>   [warn] ==== scalajars repo: tried [warn]
>   http://scalajars.org/repository/com/google/gson/gson/2.1.0/gson-2.1.0.pom
>   [warn] ==== SecureSocial Repository: tried [warn]
>   http://securesocial.ws/repository/releases/com.google.gson/gson/2.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [warn] ==== public: tried [warn]
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gson/gson/2.1.0/gson-2.1.0.pom
>   [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>   [warn]    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::
>   com.google.gson#gson;2.1.0: not found [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [error]
>   {file:/Users/levinotik/Dev/scala/throw-away/myFirstApp/}myFirstApp/*:update:
>   sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
>   com.google.gson#gson;2.1.0: not found [error] Total time: 4 s,
>   completed Dec 20, 2012 10:53:52 PM

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a mistake in the groupId, it is "com.google.**code**.gson":

```
"com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.2"
```