# Parse Jackson JSON array of integers to Java array without using extra classes

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an array of integers

```
[2, 41, 52, 54, 23, 65, 4]
```

How to parse these values into a simple Java integer array from that JSON array without using extra classes? Is that possible?

Comment: *without using extra classes* - Why? Do you mean external libraries?

Comment: @cricket_007 No. I mean model classes. Usually developers use model classes for doing that job and tutorials on youtube are showing only that way of parsing. But I need just an array.

Comment: Ah, then you really don't need Jackson

Comment: yeah but I'm using play framework.. It uses only Jackson

Comment: guess I have to go back to spring

Comment: Really?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984046/trying-to-include-gson-in-play-2-0-project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Just like you would do with any other object:

```
public class ParseArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "[1, 2, 3]";
        int[] array = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, int[].class);
        System.out.println("array = " + Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This example could help you:

JSON : {"integers":[2, 41, 52, 54, 23, 65, 4]}

`JSONArray array = obj.optJSONArray("integers");`

Then:

int[] integers = new int[array.length()];